# Distribute circles with different distances and size

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm looking for a way to distribute circles of different sizes and distances in relation to a center point evenly and preferably without collision.

In case of a inevitable collision I want  to reduce them to one circle.

The data available for a circle are distance and size.

I just can't seem to be able to wrap my head around it and hope you peepz might be able to help me out

EDIT:

In the image below you can see the expected result. The information available for points `P1` to `P6` are `distance` and `size`. The points should be distributed evenly, so cluttering in one area should be avoided, but i think that does not take priority. Mainly I'm interested in avoiding collision and an attempt to distribute.

I hope this cleared up a few questions.

[image: Image displaying the expected result]

Comment: I think a hand-drawn diagram would better get your intent across.

Comment: Can circle C1 be inside circle C2?

Comment: Do you care if the circles are all close, or do you want to maximize the minimum distance between circles, or achieve some other distribution?

Answer (score 0):

As "distance" I understand "*distance to the origin*".

As "evenly distributed" I understand "*evenly angle-distributed*"

So, what I think is that each circle `Ri` must be set in some point of a circle centered at origin with radius = distance `di`.

Consider this image, where two circles with radius `R1` and `R2`are tangent, the "minimum" overlap:

[image]

All of a,b,c distances are known:

a = R1 + R2

b = d1, distance to R1

c = d2, distance to R2

The angle `g` can be found by `cos(g) = (b^2 + c^2 - a^2) / (2*b*c)`.

So that angle `g= acos(b^2+...)` is the minimum between those two circles.

First try to put the `n` "points"; this is, calculate angles:

g1 = 0

g2 = g1 + 2Pi/n = 1 * 2Pi/n

...

gi = i * 2Pi/n

Then choose an order or circles. For example, bigger come first. Or better alternate bigger and smaller.

Then test if the angle `2Pi/n` makes some overlap. This happens if `2Pi/n <= gij` for some `gij= gj-gi` between a circle and the next. Calculate `gij` with the 'acos'  formula above.

In case or overlap between Ri and Rj you may move the second (Rj, increase its `gj`) and distribute this increment in the rest of angles.

Don't forget to test if the last circle overlaps the first one.

In case you still have overlaps, then change the order of circles and start again. Perhaps there is a better method.